# Is there any alternate method to implement Resultset row_number() and use it to get records between ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get records in a result set between `Row_number()` from multiple tables using an `INNER JOIN`.

The problem is that all tables have columns with the same name and it I get an error

> The column 'DEPT_DSCR' was specified multiple times for

Keep in mind the query inside the result set is auto-generated from a procedure, so I cannot add aliasing or anything.

This is the way I'm writing my query

```
with resultset as 
(
     select  
         row_number() over (order by a.a) rownumber, 
         g.dept_dscr, i.dept_dscr 
     from 
         abc a  
     inner join 
         def g on g.dept_no = a.b  
     inner join 
         ghi i on i.dept_no = a.c 
     where 
         a.b = '640' and a.c = '640'
) 
select * 
from resultset  
where rownumber between 1 and 12 
order by rownumber
```

I'm new to SQL Server so pardon me if the question looks complicated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Note that for your application to properly read the data, each column needs a unique name too; so using aliases would seem key here too.

Comment: *"Keep in mind the query inside the RESULTSET is auto-generated from a procedure, so I cannot add aliasing or anything."* What does that mean? You can't use syntax like `WITH CTE AS(EXEC SP) SELECT * FROM CTE;` so there's no way that you could have the result set come from a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to the row number, but to the fact that you return two columns with the same name. The table name or table alias is not part of the returned column name, so r.dept_dscr and i.dept_dscr are regarded the same.

If you need both, you can give one of them an alias (or both), by changing `i.dept_dscr` to `i.dept_dscr AS some _alias`, where some_alias is an identifier of your choosing.

Comment: I knew the problem that I was facing. I even specified the error in the question but I didn't highlight it... @marc_s edited it correctly. 

The reason I asked for an alternate way for row_number(), is because it was a necessary requirement.

Anyways aliasing was my only option. But, as the inner query was being taken care of by an SQL Procedure, written by our DB Team, I had to raise a ticket to get aliasing added by the Procedure itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can more simply write this query without a CTE:

```
 select row_number() over (order by a.a) as rownumber, 
        g.dept_dscr, i.dept_dscr 
 from abc a join
      def g
      on g.dept_no = a.b join
      ghi i
      on i.dept_no = a.c 
 where a.b = 640 and a.c = 640  -- things that look like numbers usually are
 order by rownumber
 offset 0 fetch first 12 rows only;
```

Ironically, if you write it like this, you will not have a problem.  SQL Server allows result sets to duplicate column names -- but not views, subqueries, or CTEs.

Nevertheless, it is better to identify where the columns come from:

```
 select row_number() over (order by a.a) as rownumber, 
        g.dept_dscr as def_dept_dscr,
        i.dept_dscr as ghi_dep_dscr
 . . .
```